# How to access Jar from Oracle 12.2 Environment

Tags: java, oracle

1. Created a Jar file with two classes which are dependent.
2. Loaded the jar from SQLite
3. The classes inside the jars are in Invalid state.
4. To call the class, Created a function as below
5. Classes are valid now.
6. Calling the class as

   ```
   loadjava -user schema/Pwd jarName.jar
   ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkclass1 RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Calling.class2fn () return java.lang.String';
```

```
select checkclass1 from dual;
```

```
ORA-29531: no method class2fn in class Calling
29531. 00000 -  "no method %s in class %s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to execute a non-existent method in a
           Java class.
*Action:   Adjust the call or create the specified method.
```

Should show the output of the dependent class as

```
Hello World
```

Comment: public class Calling {
 
     Called c=new Called();
     String s;
     public String class2fn()
     {
     s=c.class1fn();
     return s;
     }
}


public class Called {
  public static String class1fn()
   {
     return "Hello world";
   }
}


Class Details

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57203775/edit) to add information, particularly code; and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post.